# Rails 5 catch-all for request formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

In Rails 5 routes.rb I have a catch-all in the end with:

```
match "*path" => "static_pages#not_found", via: :all
```

In combination with the action this works well to handle useless URLs like "/bla" or "/bla.html". But for existing routes with different request formats this is not working. For example I have working URL "/authors" and useless "/authors.jpg" is getting:

```
AuthorsController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["image/jpeg"] request.variant: []
```

on development and HTTP 406 on production.

I wish to have the unhandled request formats even handled by my not_found action. What is the Rails 5 way to catch-all also request formats?

source is https://github.com/muhme/quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use defaults in your routes to be more strict with your routing. I'm not convinced this is the best option though http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults

```
defaults format: :html do
  resources :authors
end
```

I think the better solution would be to `rescue_from` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_from

Use `ActionView::MissingTemplate` in `rescue_from`. I would probably setup some sort of error notification though to alert you when these happen still.

```
rescue_from ActionView::MissingTemplate do |exception|
  # render 404 and/or email yourself a notification
end
```

Comment: Hey @dft, thx for your answer.I tried to set default format in routes, but w/o any effect. /authors.jpg or /authors/1.jpg are still raising ActionController::UnknownFormat

Comment: and rescue_from ActionView::MissingTemplate or ActionController::UnknownFormat in ApplicationController also shows no effect (exception isn't caught)

Comment: you're right catching is the right way and now working for me on 2nd try, thx

Answer (score 1):

In the end working for me working is ApplicationController:

```
rescue_from ActionController::UnknownFormat do |exception|
  redirect_to(controller: 'static_pages', action: 'not_found', original_url: request.original_url)
end
```

Together with corresponding action:

```
def not_found
  @original_url = params[:original_url]
  if @original_url.blank?
    @original_url = request.original_url
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.all { render :status => 404, :formats => 'html', content_type: "text/html" }
  end
end
```